# Equal height border lines for divs that have float:left

Tags: css, css-float, border

I'm trying to achieve a same height border line between divs that are floated left using display:table-cells. I understand that if I change float:none, the heights of the divs are equal but for some reason I can't change float:left to none.

Is there a way to make the divs equal height with float:left ?

See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gMmk.png) to explain the problem and what I'm trying to achieve

Code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .c-grids {display:table}
        .c-grid {display:table-cell;float:left;border-left:1px solid red;padding:0 20px;}
        .c-grids input {display:block;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="c-grids">
        <DIV class="c-grid c-grid-1of4">
            name<INPUT type=text autocomplete="off" name="text1" value="">
        </DIV>
        <DIV class="c-grid c-grid-2of4">
            <INPUT type=text autocomplete="off" name="text2" value="">
        </DIV>
        <DIV class="c-grid c-grid-3of4">
            <INPUT type=text autocomplete="off" name="text31" value="">
            <INPUT type=text autocomplete="off" name="text32" value="">
        </DIV>
        <DIV class="c-grid c-grid-4of4">
            <INPUT type=text autocomplete="off" name="text41" value="">
            <INPUT type=text autocomplete="off" name="text42" value="">
            <INPUT type=text autocomplete="off" name="text43" value="">
        </DIV>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
CT

Comment: share here you should try your code

Comment: You can try adding `min-height: 100px` to every `div`.